# Android - What is the difference between a foreground and background service?

Tags: android, operating-system

From android.com it says that a foreground service is something that the user is aware of and a foreground service is unlikely to be killed if memory is needed. It says a background service may be killed if memory is needed. Is this the only difference or can one service offer extra features?

My main question is, why would a background service be used if it is likely to be killed. Can anyone provide an example of an app would use a background service?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> Is this the only difference or can one service offer extra features?

To have a foreground service, you have to show a `Notification` in the status bar. Ideally, that `Notification` gives the user the ability to control the operation of the app, such as to stop whatever the foreground service is doing (e.g., playing music).

> why would a background service be used if it is likely to be killed

Among other reasons, users get very cranky if you add icons to their status bar without a good justification for having them there.

In general, you use *neither* type of service, [unless it is actively delivering value to the user](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). Many background services are short-lived, doing a particular bit of work (e.g., checking a mail server for new messages) and going away. There is no strong reason to have a foreground service for that work, though a few developers will do that anyway.

> Can anyone provide an example of an app would use a background service?

Most of the apps on your device use background services.

Comment: Good content. I enjoy reading the link. I feel proud I haven't used `Service` way out of its real purpose :)

Comment: this is the best answer i have seen related to this topic